# Custom form in WordPress and store values into custom database

Tags: mysql, wordpress, forms

I have a simple form with 2 text fields in my WordPress site. I created a new page template and added the following HTML code:

This is the HTML:

```
<form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" id="customform" method="post">
Field 1: <input type="text" name="field1" id="field1">
Field 2: <input type="text" name="field2" id="field2">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

Now all I want to achieve, is that whatever the user inputs, it stores it to `mySQL` (**which is in the same database as WordPress**), in the table `test_form`, for example.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: can you provide the test_form table layout? there is a good example here http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: The table layout for test_form is simply Field1 (VARCHAR), Field2 (VARCHAR).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it by the following code:

```
<?php
    include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wordpress/wp-config.php');

    $field1 = $_POST['field1'];
    $field2 = $_POST['field2'];
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->query(
        $wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO wp_test_form ( field1, field2 ) 
            VALUES ( %d, %d)",$field1,$field2)
    );      
?>
```

**NOTE**: Tested with **table** called **wp_test_form**. You can add your own **table name**. It is for integer value.If you want **string** then change `%d` to `%s`.

Comment: You wrote "If you want string then change %d to %s". What happenes if it is a date format?

Comment: Also, if when you submit the form, it adds 2 additional blank rows into the database. How can I fix this? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it will help you.

```
  $field1   =   $_POST['field1'];
  $field2    =   $_POST['field2'];
  $page_one_table = 'test_form';
  $page_one_inputs =  array(
  'field1' => $field1,
  'field2' => $field2
  );
//  Insert the data into a new row
  $insert_page_one  =   $wpdb->insert($page_one_table, $page_one_inputs);
  //    Grab the ID of the row we inserted for later use
$form_id = $wpdd->insert_id;
```